# show soft keyboard after already hidden and editbox focused

Tags: android, show, hidden, android-softkeyboard

I have a problem that is only reproducing on 2.3 devices.
Basically, I have an activity with two EditTexts which are both focusable and the user can input anything in them.
When I switch from portrait to landscape, I have a requirement that says that the virtual keyboard should not be displayed. To achieve this, on OnConfigurationChanged I use InputMethodManager's hideSoftInputFromWindow.
However, if let's say that field 2 was focused in the portrait mode, when I switch to landscape mode, the field is focused but pressing on it doesn't open the keyboard.
I even forced it to open with:

```
edittext2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
InputMethodManager keyboard = ( InputMethodManager )
getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE );
keyboard.showSoftInput( v, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

but the keyboard doesn't appear on either.

It seems that, because it is already focused and a previous keyboard was displayed and hidden, the system decides not to open another one.

Can you suggest me a quickfix for this?

**LATER**

Finally solved this using this little nasty workaround before calling *showSoftInput*:

```
edittext2.clearFocus
edittext2.requestFocus
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this method;

```
 public static void setKeyboardFocus(final EditText primaryTextField) {
    (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            primaryTextField.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0, 0, 0));
            primaryTextField.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 0, 0, 0));
        }
    }, 100);
}
```